# Bootstrap 4 Image product didn't line up properly

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm tryin to make a simple online shopping page for my PHP training.
But, I'm kinda stuck in the HTML part where using bootstrap didn't make 
something more simpler.

The result of the code makes my product line up vertically, and what I want to with it is to make it line up horizontally.

**Code :**

```
<div class="container">

<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'cart');
$query = 'SELECT * FROM products ORDER by id ASC';
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

if ($result):
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0):
    while ($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):
      //print_r($product);
      ?>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <form class="" action="welcome.php?action=add&id=<?php echo $product['id'] ?>" method="post">
          <div class="products">
            <img src="<?php echo $product['image']; ?>" class="img-fluid text-center" />
            <h4 class="text-info"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></h4>
            <h4>$ <?php echo $product['price']; ?></h4>
            <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control" value="1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $product['name'] ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php echo $product['price']; ?>" />
            <button type="submit" name="add_to_cart" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Add to Cart</button>

          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <?php
    endwhile;
  endif;
endif;

 ?>
```

Comment: Read the [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#how-it-works). `col-*` must be placed in `row`.

Comment: Oh my god ! Thx man. And sorry for the silly question cuz I missed some part of the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For bootstrap grid system to work , the tags must be in following order:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      One of two columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      One of two columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```